# hg clone has stopped working on my Vista box

Tags: windows-vista, networking, mercurial

I have a Windows Vista machine that has been connecting to http://hg.netbeans.org productively for awhile... until recently.

Lately, when I attempt to pull or clone, the update appears to stall...

I see the following messages on the screen when I attempt to clone (with --debug):

```
using http://hg.netbeans.org/web-main
sending between command
destination directory: web-main
sending heads command
requesting all changes
sending changegroup command
adding changesets
changesets: 1 chunks
add changeset 203e82b1b502
changesets: 2 chunks
add changeset 746047ca7781
changesets: 3 chunks
.
.
.
changesets: 3407 chunks
add changeset 475299c33a81
changesets: 3408 chunks
add changeset 71fbe52ec211
changesets: 3409 chunks
add changeset edcd21a471b5
```

And then... nothing happens.

I have opened the Task Manager and there doesn't appear to be any significant network activity for HOURS.

I can contact the server with FireFox and see the proper output.

I can clone from the repo with Solaris and/or Mac OS X... so the issue doesn't appear to be at the 'other end'.

I had been running a fairly old version of Mercurial successfully before this started happening.  After it started happening, I upgraded to Mercurial 1.5.2.. which did not help resolve the issue at all.

What are the likely causes and work-arounds for this?

Comment: Was it working before? Do you see anything happening network wise? Have you tried with --debug?

Comment: Same here, it freezes without any error on Windows Server 2008 SP2 with TortoiseHg 1.0.3 or Mercurial 1.5.4 (at different steps)

Comment: Have you been able to fix this in the mean time? If so, then please provide an answer below. @alexandrul: did you try asking on the Mercurial mailinglist: mercurial@selenic.com?

Comment: @MartinGeisler: at this moment it works for me on Windows Server 2008 x64 with hg 1.9.3

Comment: @alexandrul: okay, it's good to hear that. So I guess upgrading is the answer here.